# How can I finance a car at 17 years old with no credit or co-signer?

Tags: car

I just turned 17 on March 17th. I will be graduating high school next year. However, I'm looking to purchase my first car or least drop a down payment of $20,000 on a new 2021 cla Mercedes Benz on my own. How would this work if I'm only 17, and my mother doesn't want to help (co-sign or at least help me get the car). I have no credit history also. I'm interested in the car and have the cash to do so!

Comment: "Help I'm interested in the car and have the cash to do so!" No you don't - you have $20k and need to _borrow_ the rest.

Comment: You mention you have the cash to buy the car. Do you have a quote from an insurance provider for a 17 year old driving a $20k car, and can you afford that sum also?

Comment: @JamesPD: Note that it's not a $20K car, it's a new Mercedes with a $20K DOWN PAYMENT.  Google says the MSRP starts at $37,850 and goes up to $55,350 or more dependng on options.  Maybe we should be asking the OP how big his trust fund is :-)

Comment: On top of the many good answers already posted here, also consider that the upfront purchase price of a car is _cheapest_ part of owning one. Do you also have money for insurance (not cheap when you're 17, nor for a car with >300 hp)? Maintenance (not cheap when it's a Mercedes)? Gas?

Comment: It would help if you gave a brief indication of *why on earth* you consider buying a new Mercedes. It is probably a good, attractive car; but *what specifically* makes you want to pay an added 20,000 dollars or so for only marginal advantages over a decent used non-Mercedes?

Comment: @BABYFACEVET FYI, $20k is about the total cost of my 4 year degree, and a decent down payment on a home in some areas. There's quite a bit you can do with that money, and a lot of cars you can buy outright with it, especially if you let someone else break in the engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Buying my first car out of college](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/buying-my-first-car-out-of-college)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [By 18 years of age, I want a brand new car that's $43,668](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/by-18-years-of-age-i-want-a-brand-new-car-thats-43-668)

Comment: How much money do you have or will you have when you are wanting to buy the car?

Comment: And where will the rest of the money come from?

Comment: Are you willing to divulge how you came to have the $20k?  I think the answer is substantially different if this was a GME YOLO vs an inheritance vs saving some sort of income over an extended period.

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying this is the *right* suggestion, but have you considered looking at electric vehicles? They're cheaper to "fuel" and maintain, so you might find you can afford a $30k EV easier than a $30k gas car. It's worth considering, though I wouldn't necessarily recommend a $30k car as a first car at 17.
Perhaps I'm not one to talk, I got my first car (Tesla Model 3 SR+) at 24 years old.

People are right though, insurance can be a b****...

Comment: Go thank your smart mother for not co-signing. Just browse this site for "co-signing" and you know why.

Comment: It's just too big a first step into the car purchase arena. A new Mercedes is just too expensive for any moderate-income person, let alone a 17 year old. I'd even advise against secondhand Mercs as the cost of parts is crazy. Get a nice smart secondhand Honda or Toyota (a female previous owner and low mileage) and get it under 3-5 year loan secured by your lump sum safely put away for the bank to see. You'll have enough to do learning how to do basic servicing and valeting it for the next couple of years. Believe me, at your age money in the bank is the best credit record you could ever have.

Comment: I'm a young male driver. My first car was a small Mercedes A-Class I inherited from my grandfather. It was honestly a nightmare to drive; I just wasn't experienced enough to be able to drive it well and as a result of that I really didn't enjoy it, to the point I minimised using it. It was a target for the police and eventually my dad accidentally destroyed it... Afterwards I got a small second-hand Skoda Citigo eco-green which I love so much. That's my real first-car.

Comment: I bought my first car at 23.  I paid all cash.  More importantly, the car was 10 years old and in great condition.  I was not obligated to a co-signing parent, nor to a high interest rate loan.  FREEDOM! (*breathe...*)

Comment: "my mother doesn't want to help" Listen to her, she's the voice of reason

Comment: @quid somebody is going to read your comment in five years and go "wut?"

Comment: If you live in an area where there is snow in the winter, I would never recommend having a new car for your first vehicle.  Odds are you will have at least one driving incident your first winter.  There is a reason people with nice cars have 'winter beaters'.

Comment: Which jurisdiction is this?

Comment: If you have $20k to spend on your *first* car, then go and buy a $10k car, so you have another 10k in your pocket to fix it/replace it when you inevitably break it.

Comment: An inexperienced driver getting a very expensive car with a lot horse power, what could possibly go wrong? Joking aside, I estimate 50% of my friends had accidents in their first 5 driving years. That ranged from scratching the bumpers on a wall to completely wrecking a Mercedes on the Autobahn. So in addition to the price tag, please check if you can afford the repairs or another smaller car after you crashed the first one.

Comment: Can a 17 year old even buy a used vehicle? Can they legally sign the paperwork?

Comment: A cheap car that works costs less than $5000. If this car costs $50000 then you're going to have $45000 less for the *rest of your life*. Is that what you want? You'll be 30 and want a nice vacation, but you can't have one, because you spent that money on a car (that you don't even have any more). You'll be 65 and want to retire, but you have to work for another year because you spent that money on a car. Is it good?

Comment: If the location is in the usa then what does it matter? No dealership and/or lender is going to take just your signature. You are under age and the contract is null and void.

Comment: Don't worry, insurance will put an end to this idea. When I was 18 I found a sweet deal on this serious muscle car. Huge engine and huge horsepower to go with it. I had to have it and I had the money myself. I was all set to buy it, and then my dad checked on how much adding that car to his insurance policy would cost. The answer was a lot, plus "We'll drop you at the next renewal period if your son buys that car."

Comment: If you really want a luxury car (you don't need one, but I get it) then find one that you can pay in cash. Look at Acura or Lexus. Service and insurance costs will be lower with these cars also.

Comment: If everyone who upvoted @computercarguy's "Does this answer your question?" comment had flagged the question as a duplicate instead, this Q would have been closed by now.

Comment: How much do you make per month?

Comment: @shoover: Yes, it would have been closed, so we wouldn't have the interesting question to kick around :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I leased my first Merc at 21 - an SLK 180 convertible, followed by a C-Class 300 coupe, then a GLC 63s AMG.

Slightly scared that you want to drop $20k on a CLA... if you've got the means for that at 17 you won't be satisfied for long.

I found that the cost of a good lease was often less than or at least comparable to the depreciation on buying a new vehicle, without the CapEx. In other words, what's the point of buying it at all? $20k will more than cover a 3 year operating lease in full and you've got that in cash.

If it was me, I'd opt for a 2 year lease and pay 12+ months of it up front. Paying several months up front is a solid way to offset the lack of credit history. You'll get the CLA, have plenty left in the bank, and be able to upgrade to a real car in a couple of years.

Edit: for reference, my first SLK in 2012 was (converted from GBP):

- 24 Month Contract
- 6 + 23 Payment Profile
- 10,000 Miles per annum
- $365 per month
- Initial Payment $2,174

TOTAL COST over 2 years? ~$10,600

No idea why you'd want to drop $20k cash + monthly payments to buy a CLA.

Comment: I'm so glad this story had a happy ending :)

Comment: I love how the answer with 124 upvotes isn't accepted, but it's the one with 3 upvotes. I guess people hear what they want to hear

Comment: @dberm22 I think it's because this answer came from someone who was in a similar situation and gave simple figures. rather than a wall of text (even if I read the walls myself).

Comment: @dberm22 - It's likely because the upvoted question gave a lot of (good, IMHO) unsolicited advice, instead of simply answering the question. I've given some answers like that myself. This was a better answer, even if the OP would be better served by the other one.

Comment: @Clockwork No, it's because this answer tells OP what they wanted to hear, not what they needed to hear. A 17 year old driving a $30,000-$40,000 car around is absolute bonkers. Does this kid even make $30,000 a year? This kid is going to get swindled at the Merc dealership... they'll just see $$$ walking in from an inexperienced child without a parent present to provide oversight. Oh well, some of us are hell-bent on learning super painful lessons the hard way...

Comment: I mean, $20,000 is a down payment on a house!!!! An appreciating asset... this child wants to plop it down on an asset that loses 1/4 of it's value the moment he signs the paperwork, and continues to depreciate after that. Plus, insurance on a 17 year old driving this kind of car around will be bonkers, and if it's leased it'll be double-bonkers. This is perhaps the single worst financial decision this child can make in their entire lifetime.

Comment: Upgrade to a real car?  Be serious!

Comment: @SnakeDoc I see what you mean, but the answer does point out that they won't be satisfied even if they could do it. Maybe the asker did only read the parts that they wanted to hear.

Comment: The great thing about this answer is that it allows the OP to achieve his goal without going into debt. Yes, the 20,000 will have been effectively wasted after 2 years (or sooner, lease + insurance), but OP will still be debt-free and will have learnt from first-hand experience whether it was "worth it" or not.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The OP does not give overview of his financial possibilities. Does 20K for you mean the same as 20K for the OP?

Comment: @dberm22: the answer with the most upvotes is based upon the assumption that the OP is an average 17yo, which obviously isn’t the case or the OP wouldn’t have 20k in cash.  While it isn’t bad advice, it’s not necessarily relevant to the OP.  This answer tells the OP how to get what is wanted,while leaving it to the OP to decide if it’s worth the price.  And pointing out that the price is simply a loss, which is true whether the OP leases or buys. The difference being that if you lease,you don’t have a vehicle but you don’t have any debt either. If the OP is making enough, it’s probably better

Comment: @AskarKalykov OP is a 17 year old who requires a parent for co-signing on this car (meaning they do not have the means to borrow or pay off the vehicles on their own) - ie, they aren't some millionaire-youtube-star or whatever you might be imagining.

Comment: [A minor can't lease a car](https://www.leaseguide.com/articles/teen-car-leasing/). Leasing is a form of financing and requires a contract, which brings us back to the same problem as before. The leasing agency will require a legal adult that they can hold responsible if the terms of the lease are violated.

Answer (score 146):

My grandson bought an expensive new car on hire purchase when he was 19. It was a millstone round his neck for several years. It wasn't as expensive as a new Mercedes, but more than I ever spent on a car, and much more than he wished he had spent.

As far as your mother doesn't want to help by co-signing: If you followed this site, people co-signing and then ending up paying is one of the [most often repeated questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-sign). My rule is: If I have the money, and if I want to give it to you, I'll give it to you. If I don't have the money, or I don't want to give it to you, then I won't give it to you. Never, ever, in a million years, will I co-sign for you. And that's what I would tell your mother if she posted here

My youngest granddaughter managed to get about £2,000 from various people as presents, and from a part-time job, when she was 18. She bought a car for £2,000. She has all the freedom that having a car gives you. If you think that you can pull because you drive around in Mercedes, that doesn't work, because any intelligent girl or boy will know that you are over your head in debt, and that makes you actually very unattractive.

And I think you may not have looked at the cost of driving a Mercedes. Your insurance cost will eat you alive.* If you were an insurance company, would you want to insure a brand new Mercedes driven by a 17 year old? I certainly wouldn't. Servicing will cost. Mercedes dealers are rich. Why are they rich? Because people like you pay them tons of money for service.

It's quite simple. If you tell me "I have enough money to buy two Mercedes", then go ahead and buy one. If you don't have that money, don't buy it.

*Call a local insurance company for a quote. That alone might change your path.

Comment: Suddenly, I'm tempted into asking about buying music instrument, just so that someone can answer the way you did. It goes very much indepth into the small details that are missed from first timers.

Comment: @Clockwork I would expect exactly the same answer if someone proposed buying a musical instrument for $50,000. More so unless they were planning on using the instrument to make a living.

Comment: @DJClayworth a musical instrument worth $50000 probably wouldn't lose 30% of its value the first time you touch it, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil If you're really good it might even appreciate in value.

Comment: @EricDuminil Very true!  But really for a 17 year old the same basic rule would apply: "if you have to ask..." .  A super expensive instrument might be appropriate for a prodigy, but they wouldn't have to ask on SE how to afford it.  Likewise, whatever is to be said about the wisdom of someone having this car so young, if you ask how to buy this car here there's no way you can afford it.

Comment: So for fun I got a quote for the OP's situation.  Considering it will have to be financed (meaning it will be required for the OP to have comprehensive insurance), you are probably looking at a minimum of $8,500 per year for insurance alone, and more realistically 10-12k per year.  Might be useful to add to answer! (I just ran a quote on a insurance comparer for a 17 yo male for this model of car, I even assumed a good student discount!)

Comment: @eps and all that only goes up, **WAY** up, after the first accident, and, assuming the OP survives, the car is probably gone. A 300 hp car is no joke. At least it is a front-wheel drive, but that's still a very powerful car. My youngest sister got into some pretty bad accident in a low-end vehicle, totaled her own car, the other car was actually relatively undamaged (rear ended someone, sharp braking, engine hit into bumper of other vehicle). She was unable to get insured as an individual for 5 years, and as an occasional driver it doubled my parent's insurance...

Comment: "If you think that you can pull because you drive around in Mercedes, that doesn't work, because any intelligent girl or boy will know that you are over your head in debt" - I doubt many teens would be able to accurately judge someone's financial situation or understand debt well, but certainly the people worth knowing don't care how much money you have nor what you drive, and the people who do care about money won't care about you unless you also bring all the other things they tend to associate with money (like charisma and buying and paying for a lot of other things you can't afford).

Comment: @nelson I agree with all the sentiment of "don't get that car" but for a careful driver, having a car like that actually helps in an accident. I was the kid who's dad had the cash and I drove cars like that (didn't own them, but dad let me drive them) and I drove carefully, when a moron ran a green light and sheared the front of the bmw I was sitting in off, I left with barely a scratch. Had I been sitting in a less heavy duty, awesome breaks, safety conscious car I would likely not be here.

Comment: This is a reasonable point of view which I share, but it's definitely NOT an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Re "*And I think you may not have looked at the cost of driving a Mercedes.*", My friend has a saying: "Some people can't afford a free car." I'd say it's more than "some". Also, some free cars are more expensive than others as they have different insurance and maintenance costs.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of Janis' song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qev-i9-VKlY

Comment: @EricDuminil I think the initial loss of value is the same for any goods, unless they are too high in demand. The value is lost because an ad saying "this accordeon is totally new, bought it two days ago and haven't even played it" is suspicious at least.

Comment: @Džuris: The most expensive instruments I've seen were all in really good shape, but they were also a few centuries old. It doesn't matter much if a cello or a violin is 250 years old or 250.01 years old.

Comment: what if BABYFACEVET is trying to pull *un*intelligent girls or boys?

Comment: @NotThatGuy some of them might not care, but some of them might read money.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user253751 *"...because any intelligent girl or boy will know that you are over your head in debt, and that makes you actually very unattractive."* The money you put in that car can afford you **a lot** of prostitutes instead, which is the only thing you'll be attracting with that kind of car anyway. So save yourself a lot of financial hassle (not to mention 'relationship' hassle) and cut out the proxy car.

Comment: @Servaes "The money you put in that car can afford you **a lot** of prostitutes instead" - LOL

Comment: @user253751: Even the unintelligent ones are going to see some kid whose parents let him use their car for the night :-)

Answer (score 60):

You seem to have fallen into the (very common) trap of thinking of a car as a status symbol. This means that you are prepared to pay more money, and put your overall finances at more risk, than if you think of it in  purely utilitarian way, i.e. how much use will the car be to you.

In your shoes I would be asking myself a number of questions:

- Do I actually really need a car at all? Can I make do with walking, or biking, or public transport? What are my plans after I graduate from high school, and will I still need / want a car then?
- If the answer to the above is yes, then how much of my cash savings do I want to / can I afford to spend on a car? If you're 17 and have $20,000 available and sitting there, then I'm guessing that you either have an inheritance or a generous relative, which makes it harder to really internally *understand* the value of that money versus if you'd had to earn it yourself. If you got a job as a retail store assistant, say, that would pay $x / hour, and if you also had to pay for rent and bills and food then how long would it take to save up the $20k you're thinking about spending? Do you have other uses for that $20k coming up eg university tuition, housing...
- Next question: how much do I want to / can I afford to borrow to add to the cash I am planning to spend on the car? Realistically, if you are 17 and have no credit history and no co-signer, the answer to this will be 0 no matter how much you want to add more to it. And this is a good thing, this is "the system" protecting you against yourself and preventing you getting into debt that you might well struggle to repay.
- Final question: what car can I get for the money I have available? Taking into account the running costs of the car - fuel, insurance, repairs - as well as the purchase cost of the car. The answer to this is likely to result in something very much less fancy / older than a new Merc.

I know when you're 17 and have a lump of cash it's really tempting to dream about what you could do with it, but honestly a fancy new car is one of the least sensible financial decisions you could make. If you don't want to be "sensible", think of it as trading off a status symbol now for a distinct lack of any status symbol in the future.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122852/discussion-on-answer-by-vicky-how-can-i-finance-a-car-at-17-years-old-with-no-cr).

Answer (score 32):

> Help I'm interested in the car and have the cash to do so!

**You do NOT have the cash to do so**

You don't have the money to buy it outright.  You also don't have the credit history or income to lease this car.  The bank isn't going to give a 17 year old a loan for a fancy car either.  Checking a [dealership](https://www.mercedesbenzofpompano.com/global-incentives-search/2020-Mercedes-Benz-CLA-250-Sedan-Offers-US2020MBZ93fba6cad3e2fd3c57dfd7b.htm#:%7E:text=Lease%20%24379%2Fmo%20for%2036,the%202020%20CLA%20250%20Coupe), it looks like you'd have to bring almost $5,000 up-front then pay almost $400 a month to lease for 3 years (400 * 12 = 4800 a year) and that is a VERY favorable deal you likely couldn't get.

Remember, the loan payment or lease payment isn't the only cost of ownership.  You've also got to buy insurance and pay for repairs.  It's over 1k on the cheap side.

[Source valuepenguin.com](https://www.valuepenguin.com/mercedes-benz-car-insurance)
[image]

You're still in high school, and you have $20,000!  While that's not enough to buy a Mercedes-Benz, that's more than enough to buy a good car.  There are really great cars for 10k and under.  Save some of the 20k for other expense that'll happen once you graduate.  Best of all your mother won't need to co-sign so you can get whatever car you want as long as you can pay cash for it.

Remember, [new drivers get in far more crashes](https://www.safetyinsurance.com/driversafety/tips_statistics.html#:%7E:text=Driver%20Statistics&text=Nationwide%2C%2043%20percent%20of%20first,are%20involved%20in%20car%20crashes.) than more experienced ones.

> Nationwide, 43 percent of first-year drivers and 37 percent of second-year drivers are involved in car crashes.

One other note - [Toyota is the most popular brand of car for doctors](https://www.torquenews.com/1083/more-doctors-choose-drive-toyotas-any-other-brand-heres-why-and-which-brand-their-second-choice) according to medscape.

Comment: That graph assumes a normal driver, for a 17 yo new driver the insurance would be utterly astronomical.  I wouldn't be surprised if it was 7k for that type and value of car.

Comment: @eps - good point.  That graph is likely for the 25+ drivers.  At 17 I can't imagine what the insurance would look like.

Comment: Is it even possible for a 17 year old to get a loan of any kind, without a parent or other responsible adult to co-sign?

Comment: @jamesqf Hmm... Good question. At least in the U.S., I wouldn't be surprised if the answer varies by state.

Comment: OP says there is 20k in cash, 5k + 4.8k +4.8k + 4.8k is 19.4K leaving the OP with 600 in cash on a 3 year lease.  I would say there’s a good chance the OP could lease a vehicle.  Bad idea, but possible.

Comment: I did a quick quote, looks like somewhere between 8-12k per year for insurance depending on what coverage would be required. The rough translation of this from insurance language is "there is an extraordinarily good chance you are going to wrap this around a tree in < 6 months"

Comment: I was paying more than that with State Farm at 17, and that was 25 years ago with no collision and a beat up 15 year old rust bucket...and this area is below the national average for auto premiums.  Location matters.

Answer (score 24):

The short version: you can't.

The long version:
If you're under 18 (or 21 in some places), you're still a minor.  That means you [don't have the same legal capacity](https://www.upcounsel.com/minors-and-contract-law) to sign contracts as an adult would.  If you skipped town and stopped making payments, a very different set of rules apply as to how the lender could recover their damages. They might not be able to recover anything at all. No sane person is going to lend you money when they can't be certain that the loan's contract is enforceable.

That's why minors get co-signers for loans.  The co-signer is a legal adult so the lender has someone that they *know* they can collect from in the event that you default.  If you can't get someone to do that, then there's no realistic way to get a loan as a minor.  There's just way too much risk.

That aside, lenders consider things like your income and job history when making loans.  Child labor laws limit the number of hours that a minor can work and the type of work they can do (thus how much they can earn).  No lender is going to lend to someone who can't demonstrate that they have a steady, established income stream that's more than capable of covering the payments after deducting reasonable living expenses.

Note that this also applies to [leasing](https://www.leaseguide.com/articles/teen-car-leasing/) a vehicle (as recommended by the currently-accepted answer).  Leasing is a form of financing and requires a contract. Being a minor presents the same problems here as it would with getting a loan, which means you're back to needing an adult to co-sign. The leasing agency needs someone they can hold legally responsible if the terms of the lease agreement are broken.

---

Want to know the secret to buying cars? *Don't finance them*.  If you have $20k to drop on a down payment, do yourself a favor and set yourself up to avoid wasting money on loan interest for the rest of your life.

1. Find a used vehicle that's $6k or less and buy it in cash.  You might be amazed at how spectacular you can make a 8-10 year old car look by [deep-cleaning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGnf8G8A8qU) it.
2. Whatever money you have left, put it in a dedicated savings account.
3. Calculate how much you'd normally pay each month if you financed a reasonable, mid-range car.  Every month, make your "car payment" of that amount into your car savings account.
4. When it comes time to buy your next car, select a vehicle that costs no more than 75% of what's in your savings account.  Pay cash for it.
5. Go back to step 3 and repeat.

By making car payments to yourself, you're *earning* interest instead of paying interest.  That puts you *way* ahead and will either let you afford vehicles that would normally be outside your price range if you financed them, or will save you tons of money to use on other things.  You can adjust the amount you pay yourself every month based on how long you tend to keep cars.  I usually keep mine for 8+ years, so I only put away about 2/3 of what a normal car payment would be.  If an emergency happens and you can't make your payment one month, no problem (just get back on track as soon as you can).

The hardest part of getting into this anti-debt cycle is putting together enough money to get started.  But you're already there!  With a little bit of financial discipline you can turn that $20k into something that will save you tens if not hundreds of thousands of dollars in interest over time.  You can waste it all now on a vanity purchase, or put yourself on a path to never have to worry about cars ever again.

Comment: The first two sentences of "the long version" summarize the problem.  The OP, being a minor, _will not be the borrower_, hence the need for a co-signer.  Moreover, the OP _will not be the legal owner of the car_, as a minor can't execute a contract.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Technically, it *might* be possible for OP to legally own the car. I've known minors who were the legal owners of their vehicles, but it was either an inheritance (no contract) or a cash purchase (contract merely documents a sale that already happened, no risk to the seller). That sort of thing can vary from one locale to the other, though, so YMMV. *Selling* that vehicle as a minor is likely a completely different can of worms, though.

Comment: Good points.  I am not a contract lawyer.

Answer (score 19):

> I'm looking to purchase my first car or least drop a down payment of $20,000 on a new...

Take the first option! Already having $20K at 17 years old is impressive, but that doesn't mean you should "drop" it on anything, especially not on half of a new car. You can get a really awesome used car for much less than $20K or even under $10K, not have any monthly payments (and no-cosigner needed), and you'd have plenty of money left over to spruce it up if you want- nice car stereo, new paint job, etc.

Something else to consider, is that even if you're a fantastic driver already, you'll be parking your car at school near other people who aren't. Whatever car you get, it's likely to get some dents in it in a high school parking lot. Worse, approximately 40% of first and second year drivers [are involved in car accidents](https://www.safetyinsurance.com/driversafety/tips_statistics.html#:%7E:text=Driver%20Statistics&text=Nationwide%2C%2043%20percent%20of%20first,are%20involved%20in%20car%20crashes.). Keep that in mind when purchasing or modifying a car, since you may not have it as long as you think. (My first car was totaled after 4 months.)

As for not having credit history yet, next year when you turn 18 you can apply for a credit card. Start off with minimal purchases such as groceries and your cell phone bill. Make sure you set up notifications/alarms to pay it off in full every month, and your credit score will start working its way up all on its own.

Comment: The "totaled" scenario is a lot worse with a new car, too - you get paid for the value of the car when it was totaled, which might only be 70% of what you paid for it just a year earlier. A used car depreciates more slowly, so you'll recover a larger portion of what you paid if the car is totaled.

Comment: I can't even count how many times people backed into my parked car in the high school parking lot. It doesn't matter how good of a driver you are, it's how bad all those others are. And in high school, they're *really bad*.

Comment: For some context on what $20,000 will get you, I bought a ‘65 mustang while a Senior in High school for $14k. (2012). You can get a kickass car with cheap maintenance for way less than you’re looking at spending.

Comment: @JPeroutek: You can go even further.  My main vehicle is an '02 Mazda Miata that I paid less than $3K for.  It's IMHO way more fun than that Mercedes would be - and I say that as someone who could easily pay cash for the Mercedes :-)

Comment: Bad drivers in parking lots doesn't just stop after high school too - I arrived at my first job interview with a literal thud by backing into the office building. I got the job though! :3

Comment: @jamesqf Zoom Zoom! My first car was a '91 Miata and I loved it to death, bought one in better condition than the beater I had in high school and still have that one to this day. Definitely more fun and reliable that a Mercedes, and a heck of a lot cheaper too. If you're in an area where harsh winters aren't a concern, then I can't imagine a cooler first year-round car for the OP.

Answer (score 14):

You say:

> I'm interested in the car and have the cash to do so!

If you really have the cash to buy the car, congratulations on having saved up close to [$70,000](https://driveaway.mercedes-benz.com.au/CLA-Class-Coup%C3%A9/CLA-200), and have ongoing income that would cover ongoing costs of insurance, fuel, servicing, roadside assistance, and so on. Since you have the cash, you don't need a loan or a $20,000 down-payment for a loan, or even a co-signer for a loan. This is impressive for a 17-year-old.

You ask:

> how would this work

In Australia (and other countries, I'd expect), how a cash purchase works is that after negotiating and agreeing on price including taxes and duties etc, you pay a small deposit to confirm the purchase and pay the balance in full with a bank cheque when the car is ready to be picked up. It's also wise to buy insurance before driving the car away.

Before you agree to the purchase of the car, however, you should have a chat with an accountant or other financial professional (but not the person offering you a car loan) to make sure that the purchase is sensible in light of your income, expenses, investment ambitions and other significant purchases, etc.

If it turns out that you don't actually "have the cash to do so", then please read the other answers.

Comment: In quite a few countries, it's not just wise but mandatory to carry insurance  before driving off in your car. That need not cover your own car, the main obligation is to be insured for damage to other cars you hit. But for a $70K car? Get full coverage.

Comment: @MSalters: Though note that there are two kinds of car insurance.  Liability, which covers damages you might do to other people, is usually required.  Full coverage (also known as collision & comprehensive, or C&C in the US) covers damage to your car, and will almost certainly be required by the lender on a financed car.  Liability will typically be much less expensive than C&C, especially for luxury brands like the Mercedes, so the OP definitely needs to know which kind he's getting a quote for.

Comment: @jamesqf: Good point about who requires what. I forgot the lender requirements. (The idea of a lender for a luxury car strikes me as somewhat idiotic - if you can't pay for a luxury car, get a cheaper one. Lending for a car makes sense if you need a cheap car to get to work, and walking or public transport is no alternative).

Comment: @MSalters It makes sense to get a loan for a luxury car if it's a business expense (e.g. if you're a photographer who's photographing the weddings of wealthy clients and you need to look professional).

Comment: @nick012000: Though arguably a professional in a job like that would be driving a van.  Maybe a Mercedes van, but still, a van :-)

Answer (score 5):

Buy a cheaper car and find out how to invest the rest in something **SAFE** that you won't touch for at least the next 10-15 years.

If you have that kind of money at 17, you need to see it as a gift of a great head start rather than a chance to "impress" people with your fancy new car.

Impress them instead with your financial savvy and ability to make good money decisions at a young age.  *THAT* would be impressive!

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this. A 17 year old shouldn't be sequestering their money away for 10-15 years. Youth is often plagued with issues with cash flow, so having a big emergency fund will prevent a young adult from taking out student loans, credit card debt, etc. If they want to invest, they should do it in a way that keeps the money accessible until they have a stable job with excess income above their basic needs.

Comment: @BlackThorn while I agree with you, either your path or SRiverNet's would be infinitely better than OP's

Comment: @BlackThorn, I didn't say "can't touch", I said "won't touch", which involves fiscal discipline on his part.  Naturally, if something happens where the money is *needed* then so be it, but to have that kind of money to start out with investing at that age...where could he be in 10 years with it?

Comment: @SRiverNet That depends on what was invested in. A "safe" investment for 10-15 years when you're 17 is not what most financial advisors would recommend, I think. Low-risk investments tend to have low returns that often run about on par with inflation. If OP made that kind of investment, then the money wouldn't be worth much more in 10-15 years than it is now, despite having a larger number used to denominate the same amount of actual value. On the other hand, something with moderate risk like an index fund could have 2-3x the value in that time frame, depending on the state of the economy.

Comment: @SRiverNet Granted, I would agree that, say, dumping it in cryptocurrency or GME probably isn't the best of plans. :)

Comment: For a 17 year old, generally the safest investment opportunities are in education. Of course, you still need to find something that's right for you (matches your skills, career opportunities in the market). But that sort of investment has decades to pay off.

Comment: @reirab: The OP might benefit from investing a few hundred in _themself_ by taking some courses on personal finance and on investment.  (I personally consider cryptocurrency a commodity and therefore too risky and too specialized for 99% of individual investors.)

Answer (score 5):

Be informed that car is an asset which **decreases** in value over time.

Maybe you should keep half of your money for emergencies - that means, those money should rest somewhere else, and you won't be touching them until you might die or lose even more money without using your emergency fund.

The other half you could invest into something (an asset) that **increases** in value over time. For example gold or dividend stocks.

I would advise you to not make any quick decisions. Just take your time and think carefully before you act. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the OP would be better served by buying something that increases in value over time. I don't agree with gold for that purpose, though - gold is a non-productive asset. The OP would be better served by stocks (which appreciate over time due to the underlying companies selling products) or bonds (which at least provide ongoing income).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a car loses value over time.  Also, a car is an asset with ongoing operational costs and capital expenses.

Comment: Separate comment: I personally wouldn't suggest a young adult invest in gold stocks, that's an overly specialized part of the market.  I would suggest an aggressive growth fund, dividends and cap gains reinvested, and let compound interest work its magic.

Answer (score 5):

What about your other financial goals, though?

Some of the other answers have briefly alluded to this, but not only do you have to consider the cost of the car, you have to consider the other things you could do with the $20,000. Personally, I purchased a $14,000 car for cash in 2015 and I've been driving it ever since; I've never really thought "gee, I really wish that I had bought *[car X]* instead."

Consider: between 1957 and 2018, the S&P 500 averaged 8% return. It's averaged about 10% since its inception. If you invested the $20,000 in an IRA and retired at 67 with annually compounding 8% interest, you'd have $938,032.25. At 10%, you'd have $2,347,817.06. Even with only $10,000, at a 10% interest rate you'd have just short of $1.2 million. The recommended amount for retirement age is between $1 million and $1.5 million. All without ever adding a single penny.

Also, you have to consider other financial goals, like buying a house eventually, having emergency savings, and going to college. And, of course, it's never too early to start thinking about retirement. Most people save far too little for retirement and start saving far too late.

Spending every penny you have on a new car will not leave you any money for your other financial goals. (If you don't have other financial goals in mind yet, this would be an excellent time to set some). Think about yourself in 10, 20, or 30 years; what would you like yourself to have done with the money? Would your 40-year-old self tell you to spend all $20,000 on a new Mercedes?

To give a personal example, I invested a portion of the money I was given for my high school graduation in a mutual fund. It's increased by several times over since then, and I only spent a portion of it recently on a major purchase that I never would have thought to save for as a teenager. I've never regretted saving that money, and the fact that I still have that mutual fund today has actually encouraged me to keep saving.

Comment: The first sentence could drop "other".  Owning a car is not a financial goal, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for considering other financial goals,but -1 for assuming the S&P 500 will keep going up. Sure, invest a percentage of your money in index funds, in case it continues to go up, but also be aware that it's hardly guaranteed to keep going up and in fact you could lose half of it. I agree with more concrete investments like your education, emergency savings, and a house to live in (*not* a house to generate money).

Comment: @user253751 It's fairly close to guaranteed to keep going up over a 50-year horizon. Sure, there will be a couple of dips where half of the value disappears all of the sudden, but it always takes no more than a decade to recover from any crisis.

Comment: @TooTea now look at other countries' stock markets; now realize the USA is not special; now realize that "reversion to the mean" is a thing... sure, it *might* continue going up for the next 50 years, *or* it might just fluctuate around its current level for 20 years. Have a look at FTSE 100, STOXX Europe 50, Nikkei 225... now come up for a good hypothesis that explains why the S&P 500 should continue going up, which *doesn't* predict those indices should go up as well!

Comment: @user253751 But the USA is special, unless you envision the political situation changing wildly in the next several decades.

Comment: @user253751 I realize all those things, thank you very much. All three of the indices you mentioned are now at a multiple of where they were 50 years ago (or at their inception in the 80's). In fact,none of them experienced anything close to such a decline that would cause a net loss after 50 years. Stagnation for 20 years does not mean anything if you have 30 more years to compensate for it.

Comment: @Casey The "USA political situation changing wildly" from what starting point? On a timescale of "decades", I would predict the USA will evolve politically into either a minority white ruling class trying to deal with continuous non-white majority activist violence, or a majority non-white ruling class dealing with continuous white minority activist violence. And either way, the Chinese will be loving the economic consequences. Little sideshows like "storming the Capitol building" and "Black Lives Matter protests" are just the starter.

Comment: @TooTea They may be a multiple of where they were 50 years ago, but how about 21 years ago?

Comment: @alephzero it would be a mixed-race ruling class including white people, trying to deal with continuous white supremacist activist violence (not just white people in general). but it's off-topic, anyway

Comment: @alephzero The one where the US is the world's sole hegemonic power and largest economy and the USD the world's most important currency.  I guess if you imagine some sort of cross between Mad Max and the Warriors in the future you are right to be concerned, but I consider this unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

Many dealerships will allow you to get a loan without putting anything down - you see the ads on TV all the time ("zero down", "sign and drive", etc), which may be a smarter option. If you go that route, you'll only have to pay sales tax, delivery and any other dealership fees, title and registration, and property tax. At this point you'll probably still have $10k left over. Since there will be a lien on the car, you'll be required to have full coverage insurance, which will likely be a multiple of the quotes above - easily ~750/month. With no credit history, figure a $55k loan with a 60-month term likely has an interest rate around 10%, giving you a monthly payment of roughly $1,200 - probably more when you figure closing costs, etc, which will have to be rolled into the loan because you can't afford to pay them outright.

So after your $10k in taxes and fees, the next few months look like this:

```
When     How much cash you have left
Month 0: $9250 (you have to make the first insurance payment immediately)
Month 1: $7250
Month 2: $5250
Month 3: $3000 (need an oil change after 3 mos - $250 is fair for a new C class)
Month 4: $1000
```

Your first year of loan payments will likely only pay off about 5% of the principal, and after four months, you'll have probably paid about 1% of that principal, which leaves a balance slightly higher than what you paid for the car, and roughly twice what it's worth if you bought it brand new (assuming it's lost 40% of its value). That means that somewhere out there a lienholder owes a car dealership $55k for a car that's only worth about $30k, and you don't have any money to pay them.

So maybe a better question is... Would you give you a loan?

The sad truth is that the minute you graduate (anything), everything changes. In college, for example, nobody cares about cars. Watch Fast Times at Ridgemont High and note how they all pal around in their cars. Then Dazed and Confused - again, lots of driving, especially that truck. Then move up to college: Van Wilder, Animal House, etc. Granted in Animal House they make a tank out of a Cadillac, and indeed I had wonderful experiences after we parked a makeshift tank in front of the student union, but a Mercedes won't get you anything except the opportunity to replace a broken window and a missing hood ornament and stereo.

If you want to deviate from the norm, you have to have means and you have to be right. You absolutely MUST be right, and you need to understand that's a moving target. At one point when I was in high school I owned four cars outright - three sports cars and a Honda that had a back seat (the others were two-seaters, which causes problems). In college I had zero cars, but I had money and a cool job working with grad students as a freshman. If you work 40 hours per week at $15/hr, you won't even make enough to make minimum payments, much less eat. If mommy and daddy pay for it, you'll lack friends - independence becomes a thing at age 18, and one you won't be able to afford. If you're thinking you can "make this work somehow", the same women that like the Merc will tell you to "call them when you figure it out". Say to your friends "I saw this car the other day and I thought 'man, that's one ugly Beemer', and then I looked again and said 'wait, that's a pretty nice looking Mercedes'" and see if they laugh. If they do, you still have some figuring to do.

Comment: I don't understand the joke at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I was attending a local community college almost 40 years ago, and one of the required classes was Business Law 101. A few thing stuck in my head, such as the instructor telling us that the reason minors generally weren't allowed to make major purchases is because when they reach their majority they can demand their money back, regardless of the condition of the item purcheshed.  IIRC, the example was a kid who turned 18 on the next day went in a sporting goods store, bought a basketball and ran over it with a car repeatedly so it was totally ruined, and he could bring the carcass back to the store the next day (his 18th birthday) and claim he made a poor decision as a minor and they'd have to pay his money back.  Now the loss of a candy bar or even a bicycle isn't that big a deal, but a new car that costs 10's of thousands of dollars? Think again. That's why they want someone 18 or older to promise they'll be paid no matter what.

Comment: Is that really the law anywhere? If so, where?

Comment: https://discover.hubpages.com/education/Minor-implications-of-the-law

Comment: See [here](https://www.upcounsel.com/minors-and-contract-law) - not all contracts by minors can simply be voided at will. The article specifically mentions automobiles as a possible exception. If any minor could back out of any contract or sale at will, almost no one would sell them anything or make any kind of contract with them at all.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: It appears that each case would be judged on individual merits, and a Mercedes CLA does not appear to be a necessity even in situations where a cheaper car might be. That basketball from the answer? I can make an argument that a healthy and active lifestyle is a necessity, and buying a basketball is not an excessive expense for this purpose.